# Can I completely disable Cortana on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, cortana

Windows 10 has Cortana, which I don't like. I disabled it as soon as I could. However, looking in Task Manager, the process for Cortana is still running, and can't be effectively terminated: ending the task simply results in the process respawning a few seconds later. Using the command

```
taskkill /IM Cortana.exe /F
```

has the same result: the process respawns.

Is there any way to disable Cortana so that the process doesn't keep running in the background, and doesn't respawn if terminated?

Comment: I just followed instructions that answers bellow give, and while you can disable damn Cortana process from respawning it'll prevent you from searching for app after launching Start menu. And considering I do `WinKey+start typing to find app` quite often I needed do re-enable Cortana. Thanks M$... seems you haven't learned from IE lawsuit in 90s.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to answer, but if you have the "Anniversary Update" the toggle switch is gone. [This registry tweak](http://www.howtogeek.com/265027/how-to-disable-cortana-in-windows-10/) worked for me.

Comment: @kape123 I use start menu replacement and the search works. I like star10.

Comment: After using **MC10**'s solution below (renaming to *C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy.bak*), which worked for over a year, I think I re-enabled it by accidentally hitting **Win** + **Print Screen** for a screen shot. I'm not going to try and confirm this now that I have it disabled again.

Comment: @kape123 Be sure it's really cortana... I had a similar issue when I disabled apps running in the background (The main toggle, not the individual apps). Looks like the indexing process is disabled when background apps are disabled (even though it's not listed)

Comment: To those following the manually removing the exec route: Removing the folder will prevent _some_ updates applying. For reasons (incompetence?...) win10 does not remember that restarting didn't finalise the update in question correctly. This is a bit of an issue as it also refuses not to allow itself to reboot whenever it feels like it (some caveats). _However_ taking ownership and removing exec permissions on the files so far seems to have the best of both world: cortana is dead, not just sleeping, and the updates seems to go smoothly. I would recommend a backup though. Good luck.

Comment: Stop using windows 10.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The easiest way to disable *certain privacy aspects* of *Cortana* is to use a third-party tool such as O&O Software's free [ShutUp10](https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10).

[image: Cortana in ShutUp10]

Part of *Cortana*, though, is Windows *Search*, so there would still be an occasional *Cortana* process such as file indexing. However, there should no longer be any use of the internet by *Cortana*.

[image]

You can [remove Cortana *completely*](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3fo738/how_to_completely_remove_cortana_background/), if you wish, but that also removes Windows *Search* (though that might not be an issue if you use a third-party tool such as [*DocFetcher*](http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/en/index.html) or Mythicsoft's [*Agent Ransack*](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/), which provide increased search functionality). That said, after a Windows 10 update, expect that *Cortana* would be reinstalled. Apparently, the only way now to permanently avoid *Cortana* is to use another OS, such as Linux.

Comment: @julealgon didn't seem so unnecessary to me.  Considering it's about the only real solution there is.  That being, use something OTHER than Windows 10.

Comment: The problem is that she re-installs with every windows update...  and this is a great program, but Microsoft definitely wants here there.

Comment: This cortana is useless to me and its byte my RAM and see to get rid of I have to install another app. Cool windows.

Comment: "*Apparently, the only way now to permanently avoid Cortana is to use another OS, such as Linux.*" +1...

Comment: I deleted my earlier answer and use this now, too.

Answer (score 165):

**Update 2018: Warning about Taskbar Breakage**

I just reinstalled Windows 10 Pro and followed all the prescribed steps (both removing Cortana and removing all store apps) and it still works as prescribed.

It bears mentioning that removing Cortana will break the Default Taskbar in weird ways. It doesn't break Windows Search - so Explorer search still works in my experience.

I've, personally, always replaced the default taskbar with [Classic Start](https://ninite.com/classicstart/) (linked via Ninite installer) and have no issues in day-to-day Windows usage otherwise.

**Update: Remove Cortana via "TakeOwn"**

Apparently, this trick stopped working at some point. I've used @Meferdati's link at some point successfully: [winaero: how to uninstall Cortona](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-uninstall-and-remove-cortana-in-windows-10/). It contains a script that does all the work for you, as well as an explanation of how it works.

Below are the steps I've been using, which are very similar to [@MC10's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/949569/can-i-completely-disable-cortana-on-windows-10/949578#949578), except I've always had to "TakeOwn" to get permissions and I move my files to a different folder (instead of deleting - in case I decide to revert):

1. [add TakeOwn to the context menu](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/) or (use [takeown from the command line](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753024(v=ws.11).aspx)).
2. Navigate to C:\Windows
3. Create folder SystemApps.bak
4. Use Takeown to gain ownership of `c:\windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy`
5. (Gain ownership of anything else you want to move)
6. Cut/Paste the folder(s) from SystemApps to SystemApps.bak
7. When the "Permissions" pop-up appears, switch to Task Manager
8. Kill SearchUI.exe process
9. Switch back and give permission to move the folder

The folder is now in SystemsApps.bak - and you can simply move it back if the need arises.

**Original: Remove Cortana via Powershell RemoveAppPackage**

First disable it, then uninstall the Cortana app.

Disable it in the search settings:

1. Click the search icon/box in the bottom left
2. click the gear on the left bar
3. Click off next to Cortana/Web Searches

   [image]

Then uninstall it, as listed [here](https://superuser.com/a/942419):

In elevated PowerShell:

```
Get-AppxPackage | Select Name, PackageFullName
Remove-AppxPackage Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_1.4.8.176_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
```

This is similar to MC10's answer, except that I'm sure the OS will be more accepting of uninstalling it via the "proper channels" (powershell) instead of renaming the folder.

Windows has fixed it so now you cannot remove "...Cortana_1.6.1.52_ ...". When this is attempted it states this is part of Windows now and cannot be removed. I guess I will go back to renaming the folder.

I'm using the same uninstall to remove other "features" like BingNews, BingSports, Etc

**Edit:** Likewise, you can remove the "Provisioned" applications (aka: crap that gets installed per user) via [this method](http://blogs.technet.com/b/deploymentguys/archive/2012/10/26/removing-built-in-applications-from-windows-8.aspx)

```
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online | Select DisplayName, PackageName
Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage  Microsoft.ZuneMusic_2019.6.11821.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

Or... to remove ALL Apps that you can, app or provisionedapp, you can do this:

**Just a warning:** This will uninstall the Windows Store. That's not an issue for me, but uninstalling everything isn't for the faint of heart.

```
Get-AppxPackage | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -online
```

As mentioned in comments, it's probably wise not to completely remove the Windows Store. I haven't tried this yet, but [this (in the comments)](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/erase-default-preinstalled-modern-apps-windows-8) looks to be ballpark of what I'd use:

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name –notlike "*store*"} | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-appxprovisionedpackage –online | where-object {$_.packagename –notlike "*store*"} | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -online
```

Further resource: [Delete Windows 10 Apps](https://thomas.vanhoutte.be/miniblog/delete-windows-10-apps/) and [Restore Default Windows 10 Apps](https://thomas.vanhoutte.be/miniblog/reinstall-default-build-in-windows-10-apps/)

Comment: Considering 8.1 was distributed via the store, uninstalling the store may prevent you from installing future Windows OS upgrades.

Comment: @Bob I was wondering of anything important might be affected without the store. That would definitely count.

Comment: @Bob: So the store is an integral part of Windows that cannot be removed without breaking crucial functionality?  Ugh!  It's like 1998 all over again.  You'd think Microsoft would have learned their lesson the first time around, but apparently not... :(

Comment: Found option to "skip" Store. Now to figure out how to reinstall the store :)

Comment: @WernerCD  You can reinstall the Store app using the `Add-AppxPackage` cmdlet and the Store app’s manifest.  (For example, in Windows 8.1 you could use `Add-AppxPackage  -path %SystemRoot%\WinStore\AppxManifest.xml -register -disableDevelopmentMode`.)  Have you successfully removed Cortana this way?  When I tried to remove it using `Remove-AppxPackage` I was told that (basically) the package was shipped with Windows and couldn’t be removed that way.  I didn’t check if it was a provisioned package, though.  (I don’t have Windows 10 right now.)

Comment: @WernerCD My method breaks the search bar. I have edited that in my answer, as well as redirecting them to your answer. Just curious, does your method break the search bar?

Comment: Even running PowerShell as admin I get this: error 0x80070032: AppX / Deployment Remove operation on package
<Cortana> from: / <Cortana> failed. This app is part of Windows and cannot be uninstalled on a per-user basis.

Comment: @Vaindil Same here. This solution does not seem to work.

Comment: @Vaindil I've tried it again on a new test machine and I seem to be having the same issue now (Can't remove, Windows depends on it). I'm confident it worked at one point, but that was a few patches again. If I have the free time I'll see if it works on previous builds. Since they've added settings to disable - and blocking the application at the firewall works as well - I haven't been concerned with it.

Comment: This doesn't work. I got error saying `Remove-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CFA, Removal failed. Please contact your software vendor.` Tried running as administrator but no luck

Comment: `Get-AppxPackage` doesn't work (error). `Get-appxprovisionedpackage` uninstalls lots of crap, but not Cortana.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore. Microsoft says that the app you're trying to remove is part of windows and cannot be removed.

Comment: Check for the solution at the following link - I just ended up there because the solution mentioned above doesn't work anymore. Works as of 24.01.2016: http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-uninstall-and-remove-cortana-in-windows-10/

Comment: So I haven't gotten the full thing to work yet, but I can tell you that the first bit (getting the full package name) can be simplified in PowerShell to this: `(Get-AppxPackage | where {($_.Name.Contains("Cortana"))}).PackageFullName` - which gives `Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_1.6.1.52_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy` on my machine, suitable to put in parens or to pipe to another cmdlet.

Comment: As Meferdati mentions, this doesn't uninstall Cortona anymore... I'm not sure where it stopped, but it's been at least a few ISOs. I'll edit the answer shortly to point that out. The way I've done it isn't his answer, but I'll edit mine to include his as well as the method I've used recently. I still use the powershell script constantly to remove everything else though.

Comment: @MC10 Of course it breaks the search bar - but that doesn't bother me because I use a task bar replacement ([Ninite.com: Classic Start](https://ninite.com/classicstart/)) that has search that isn't Cortona.  Search that wants to send everything to Bing is off my list of usable products. (Sorry for the 6 month delay in response)

Comment: @MasonWheeler: What exactly happened in 1998?

Comment: @SarahofGaia Windows 98 came out, with Microsoft making the exact same bogus claim about the Internet Explorer browser that they're now making about Cortana.  It landed them in a ton of hot water and became one of the focal points in the antitrust case that came within a hair's breadth of breaking the company up.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: Corruption never learns... :(

Comment: @MasonWheeler Technically, Internet Explorer *was* an integral part of the OS. Windows Explorer wouldn't function without it, because it referenced code that resided inside `iexplore.exe`. (That could easily have been , and was, changed, however!) What they're doing with Cortana is *worse*, because Cortana is not integral to the operating system.

Comment: This doesn't or stops working with the newest update. I tried Pro part at http://www.howtogeek.com/265027/how-to-disable-cortana-in-windows-10/ and that works. I don't have Home version to test.

Comment: I couldn't find SearchUI.exe in my list of processes, so instead I had to kill Cortana in task manager and then HURRY and move the folder before Cortana restarted itself, and that seemed to work.

Comment: Removing the folder totally broke my Start Menu, everything in it turned grey. As soon as I move the folder back, the Start Menu would instantly work again. I'm gonna use Classic Shell instead..

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa I'm not sure how it affects the "normal" menu - I always install Classic Shell (Just a better search experience as well as look/feel)... then remove Cortana. This anwer was written quite a few versions of 10 ago and the hooks between Cortana and other things have, undoubtedly, gotten stronger. I don't think I've noticed anything else broken myself. I run the bottom script (remove all programs except store) > install Classic > remove Cortana on all my new installs.

Comment: I ended up removing cortana and installing Classic Shell, works a treat ! Cortana on Windows is always taking some cpu, which i hate. Many thanks

Comment: Help please. I accidentally clicked Take Ownership on the whole folder c:\windows\SystemApps. Could this cause problems?

Comment: I am unclear if this new solution still breaks search or not.

Comment: @HermanToothroth To my knowledge, removing Cortona breaks the default/builtin Windows Search Bar search... but replacement menu's such as Classic Start utilize the Windows Search (not Cortona). I remove Cortona and use Classic Start and search rather happily.

Comment: In my version of Windows (Windows 10 Home v 1709 build 16299.192), `SearchUI.exe` doesn't appear in the task manager. LockHunter sees the `SearchUI.exe` process and offers to kill it, but fails. `Cortana` processes appear in the task manager, but can't be killed. So I copied the Cortana folder instead of moving it to the backup folder. Then, LockHunter couldn't delete the original Cortana folder outright, so I chose "Delete at next system restart." We'll see if that works.

Comment: It worked, removed Cortana processes. Like Henrique, I now have a broken start menu -- it's grayed out, and I can't type or click anything. I'll try Classic Shell, though it's no longer maintained and may break when Windows 10 gets a new update.

Comment: @LarsH I've never use anything other than Classic Shell since moving to 10, so if it isn't maintained I'll keep any eye open and post my replacement if it "dies". I'm probably going to reformat my home desktop soon (been quite awhile and new job uses 7 still) so I'll update the answer if I see anything different but the basic workflow (takeown => kill task => move folder) is the process I've used since time immemorial...

Comment: this operation breaks the Search/Windows key search, it does not work anymore

Comment: @Serge I'll look the question over and see if I can highlight that but it bears mentioning: Taskbar search and Windows Search are two different things. SearchUI - aka Cortona - is used in the Default Taskbar. Not in Windows Explorer search. I just reinstalled windows last night (new SSD WHEEE!!!) and the first things I did was Remove Cortona, Remove all market apps except store and install [Classic Start](https://ninite.com/classicstart/). Everything still works as expected - but the Taskbar is definitely more integrated with Cortona - and moreso as time goes on.

Comment: @Serge updated answer to highlight the versions of my answer (Original: Remove apps, Update: Takeown and now, Warning: Taskbar breaks). Please let me know if you have any questions about it.

Comment: I see... the Classic Start has a little bit different interface than the other windows features and menus, I tried it, it looks like a patch... Another thing that it seems that is not as intelligent as Cortana... by eg for the "snipping tool" it was enough I type "capture screen" or just "screen" (it looks in the programs descriptions/tooltips texts I suppose), the classic start isn't so intelligent...

Comment: my related question here... https://superuser.com/questions/1310982/disabled-cortana-but-still-want-to-be-able-to-use-search

Comment: @Serge Yeah, honestly... I've noticed different results with the search compared to 7, but I chalked it up to 10 vs 7. I didn't spend much time with Cortana. I remove cruft and stuff I'll never use to a fault (IE: Broken task bar). You could look into the various Taskbar Replacements (Classic Start has different options... but it's mainly to "look" like previous Windows Task Bars that people were used too.). Different ones might have better search - as well as maintain the Windows 10 look and feel (not my thing).

Comment: Best win10 crapware removal post i have seen so far, and I've been looking alot, thanks.

Comment: To be the canary here: "probably wise not to completely remove the Windows Store"... I have done this and had no adverse effects so far.

Comment: @drjpizzle I don't remember adverse effects - but it's been awhile since I've gone sans-store... there are times where I want to install store apps - not often, but still convenient if it's still there. I don't think I ever found an easy way to reinstall the store app since previous attempts where I've removed the Store are long long ago in the myths of time. That might be an interesting path if I ever get that bored lol :)

Comment: @WernerCD I don't know an easy reinstall and yes: if you count missing the store as a downside[1] then ... clearly. I guess I meant no negative side effects. Thanks again for your post.
1) Babbage: "I am not able rightly to apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke one to want to install a 'ms-store app'.".

Answer (score 93):

Cortana is very integrated with Windows Search and fully disabling it will break Search. However, if you would like to keep Search functional, you can just disable the "Cortana-y" parts of Cortana.

**To disable Cortana in windows 10**

1. Press **Win + R** keyboard accelerator to open Run dialog box.
2. Type **GPedit.msc** and hit Enter or OK to open **Local Group Policy Editor**.
   Navigate to **Local Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Search**.
3. In the right pane, double click on policy named **Allow Cortana**.
4. Select the **Disabled** radio button.
5. Restart the PC and Cortana and Bing Search will be disabled. (May work after signing out and in again)

   ---

**Policy Description**

This policy setting specifies whether Cortana is allowed on the device.

If you enable or don't configure this setting, Cortana will be allowed on the device. If you disable this setting, Cortana will be turned off.

With this set, users will still be able to use search to find things on the device and on the Internet.

Comment: Search is part of Cortana. If you can do that, the process is still running, so this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It was a nice try, but didn't work. Cortana process continue running and respawing. I suggest removing the answer

Comment: I suggest leaving this answer, as it's the _only_ thing that worked for me on 1607 and wasn't utterly destructive to the start menu....

Comment: I question changing the group policy, actually disabled Cortana on Version 1607, consider the group policy specifically is ignored on Windows 10 Professional.  I agree though that based on when his question was asked, it does indeed answer the question, because it does indeed **disable** Cortana.

Comment: @ArtOfCode - true, but if you look in the details tab of task manager, SearchUI.exe (which is the Cortana process) shows up as suspended. So, this solution works perfectly.

Comment: @VijayVaradan Wow, this is a blast from the past. If SearchUI is suspended, search is also disabled.

Comment: Running 1607, this solution appears to have worked with no ill side effects.

Comment: Works great even after anniversary update. This answer FTW

Comment: gpedit.msc doesn't exist on the latest Win10.

Comment: @peterh - The `gpedit.msc` capability **does** exist within Windows 10 Professional and Enterprise operating systems, but it isn't available on a Windows 10 Home machine.

Comment: Nope this doesn't even exist in 1709

Comment: The key "Allow Cortana" does exist in 1709, but assigning a 'Disabled' to it and restarting doesn't stop Cortana. Win 10 **Pro** Version 1709 (OS Build 16229.309)

Comment: I'm seeing Cortana in task manager again (on latest version of Windows at date of writing)

Comment: Perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 59):

### Disclaimer: Please see [*WernerCD*'s answer](https://superuser.com/questions/949569/can-i-completely-disable-cortana-on-windows-10/949641#949641) for an improved method. This will break the search bar/Start search.

After playing around with it a bit, and I think I found a method.

Open **Task Manager** and have it show **More details**. Right click on **Cortana** and select **Open file location**.

[image: Task Manager]

Now find the Cortana folder, right click it, and select **Rename**. I would recommend just adding "**.bak**" to the end of the folder name so you can find it easily if you want to restore it back to it's original status.

[image: Rename]

If you attempt to rename, it will tell you that the folder is in use.

[image: Folder In Use]

This is when you want to go back to **Task Manager**, right click on **Cortana**, and select **End task**.

[image: End task]

Right after the task ends, switch back to the **Folder In Use** window and click **Try Again**. The folder should be renamed and the Cortana task will not start again.

Comment: Works a charm, and I've also used it to disable a number of other annoying processes. Thanks!

Comment: If you would like to hide the search bar, see my answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/947156/disable-cortana-completely/947164#947164 I have updated it with the method I found during the creation of this answer so scroll down to **Original Answer**.

Comment: Thanks, I've already done that though.

Comment: Technically this works, but Windows Automatic Repair will fix it if you ever have a bad boot, and Windows Update might restore Cortana. I don't suggest modifying system files just to remove a feature. It may also have unintended side effects, such as other programs that depend on Cortana code to provide some functionality (I'm not *aware* of any such dependency, but I wouldn't risk it).

Comment: I would have wrote  same answer...b'cuz I also use this method.....

Comment: Rather than posting a duplicate of [your answer from July](http://superuser.com/a/947164/21922), you should simply vote to close as duplicate.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well actually I edited that answer _after_ posting this one. My old answer on that question was a lot simpler and you can see the **Original Answer.**

Comment: Which is great! And +1 on that answer. Nice one improving it even further over the original. But it doesn't change the fact that this question is a dupe and should have been closed as one. If you really wanted to also post an answer, I'd make it a CW linking to the (updated) answer and vote-to-close.

Comment: Yeah, sounds good. I will definitely do that in the future.

Comment: I could not rename the folder because windows kept rebooting the cortana process every time I stopped it. Solution? Boot using linux mint (primary os) and rename the folder. Take that microsoft and your futile attempts to sway me!

Comment: Note: WernerCD's method just failed to work for me. PowerShell gave an error that Cortana can not be uninstalled because it is part of the operating system. The method in this answer **did** work for me. Thanks!

Comment: @ToddWilcox Did you run an elevated PowerShell (Run as administrator)?

Comment: @MC10 Yes, I modified the properties of my PowerShell shortcut (among others) to always prompt for elevation.

Comment: this is interesting, i found that the following are using cortana: https://i.gyazo.com/02c1aac208c58b22ee76704364fa6448.png
and when i went to kill processes this is what happened: https://i.gyazo.com/df91dcd03bad80eafd89a14b7fc7d6d3.png

Comment: Zombie hunter! Gotta be pretty quick on the draw to kill the Cortana daemon.

Answer (score 12):

Buried in the [privacy policy](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/privacystatement/default.aspx) for Win 10 (expand the Input Personalization section) is:

> You can turn off Input Personalization at any time. This will stop the
> data collection for this feature and will delete associated data
> stored on your device, such as your local user dictionary and your
> input history. As Cortana uses this data to help understand your
> input, **turning off Input Personalization will also disable Cortana on
> your device.** At https://www.bing.com/account/personalization, you can
> also clear data sent to Microsoft, such as your contacts and calendar
> data, user dictionary, as well as search and browsing history if your
> device also had Cortana enabled.

According to [HowToGeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/224352/whats-the-difference-between-windows-10s-express-or-custom-setup/), after installation, you can disable this by:

> If you have chosen express settings and you want to opt out of some or
> all of these, all is not lost. You can still go into the settings and
> change things.
>
> To turn off the first item found in the Personalization settings, you
> will need to open the Privacy group in Settings and then “Speech,
> inking, & typing”.
>
> Click or tap “Stop getting to know me”.

I'd strongly recommend disabling it the officially supported way over screwing with an executable.  The latter runs both the risk that Windows repair or a future Windows update to Cortana will install a new executable and re-enable it without your knowledge, or that because you removed the file the update will fail.  With consumer versions of W10 not allowing you to opt out of patches, this could result in you getting stuck in a reboot loop due to the patch failing to install or lock you out of future security updates because you don't have one of last month's required patches.

Comment: Yes, but again this doesn't stop the process running in the background.

Comment: Apparently neither will it stop Windows from [connecting to Bing whenever you type in the search box](https://windows.uservoice.com/forums/265757-windows-feature-suggestions/suggestions/9182729-do-not-connect-to-the-internet-when-cortana-and-we).

Comment: If the integrity and security of the OS is dependent on a Siri-like convenience clone as suggested, I would be significantly concerned with what other areas of it may have been compromised in such a way to achieve whatever end it is trying to make (i.e. user data). This doesn't instill much faith in me for considering this OS as viable option for any application domain requiring even minimal security (I did confirm that setting the local security policy for **Allow_Cortana** to *disabled* doesn't prevent the process from running/collecting data, making **Group Policy** an invalid option).

Answer (score 5):

Download the tool called [win6x_registry_tweak](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/152688-win6x-registry-tweak/). Now open [a command prompt with admin rights in the folder](https://superuser.com/a/1067983/174557) of the downloaded exe and run this command:

```
install_wim_tweak.exe /o /c Microsoft-Windows-Cortana /r
```

This command removes the 3 cortana packages (Cortana main package, language pack and PAL package):

```
Microsoft-Windows-Cortana-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~de-DE~10.0.10240.16384
Microsoft-Windows-Cortana-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~10.0.10240.16384
Microsoft-Windows-Cortana-PAL-Desktop-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~10.0.10240.16384
```

After a reboot your Windows is cortana free.

**ATTENTION. Make a full backup if you later when to restore it to get Cortana back. If you have not done any backup, use [those steps to generate the CABs for your Build](https://superuser.com/a/1171910/174557). Replace Flash with the MUM names of the Cortana packages. You need to generate CABs for all Cortana MUM files like here the x86 MUMs for Build 14393 [image].**

Comment: this is interesting, but for some reason its not working: https://i.gyazo.com/3fea9c6a374635688dcd3a3249242baa.png

Comment: have you made the reboot?

Comment: it went away, i renamed the system folder. This method didnt work.

Comment: @DeerSpotter what doesn't work? What have you done in detail? if you renamed a folder, the removal doesn't work.

Comment: the answer i am commenting to, that method of removing cortana doesn't work. (tested 1/22/2017)

Comment: I tested it last year with Build 10240 and it worked. Maybe it no longer works in 1607 or a newer insider build that you use

Comment: I tried this in 1607 and initially it appeared not to work, but after a couple of restarts I found that Cortana had disappeared afterall.

Answer (score 3):

For those curious what's going on under the hood with `install_wim_tweak`, it's fairly straightforward. If you prefer not to use random binaries that get total permission of your system, and also build more understanding, you can do it this way:

**THE HO-HUM USUAL REGISTRY SURGERY PART**

In the Registry:

1. Change ownership to `Administrators` of the root of the package tree:  `HKLM:\Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing`. All keys beneath that inherit from the root. The initial owner is `TrustedInstaller` like all don't-touch-this parts of Windows.
2. Change `Administrators` permission from `Read` to `Full Control` on the same.
3. Change the `Visibility` of the aforementioned 4 Cortana package keys from `2` (hidden) to `1` (visible).
4. Break the dependencies of the 4 packages by deleting all the `Owner` subkeys. The DISM interface refuses to remove owned packages as they are considered essential to the parent package.
5. Use PowerShell or plain old `dism` to remove the now-unlocked packages. A pipeline w/wildcard matching avoids the awkward long names:

`Get-WindowsPackage -Online | Where-Object { $_.PackageName -like '*Cortana*' } | Remove-WindowsPackage -Online -NoRestart`

6. Restart once manually at the end.

**BEYOND install_wim_tweak, THE UGLY PART** (WARNING: BREAKS FUTURE WINDOWS UPGRADES BECAUSE OF REASONS.)

Deleting the User-level package is considerably worse. Based on techniques [here](https://github.com/10se1ucgo/DisableWinTracking/issues/48) and [there](http://techgenix.com/sysprep-problems-app-x-packages/) and [our Windows cousin](https://superuser.com/questions/1115801/unable-to-uninstall-universal-apps-through-powershell/1115819) the unlock is not to be found in the Registry, but rather a SQLite package-tracking database: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\StateRepository-Machine.srd`

The above links have some overkill, so the boiled down version is:

1. Stop the StateRepository service: `Stop-Service -Name StateRepository -Force`
2. Take the necessary ownership and permissions of `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository` (Owner, Full Control). Use `icacls ... /save AclFile` first, for later restoration.
3. Copy the database file within: `StateRepository-Machine.srd` to a scratch area.
4. Using a decent [SQLlite editor](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) or even with an [open-source PowerShell extension](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSSQLite/1.0.3) perform the query `UPDATE Package SET IsInbox = 0 WHERE PackageFullName LIKE '%Cortana%'`
5. Save the result to the database.
6. Copy the database file back into place.
7. Restore the Ownership (`icacls ... /restore AclFile`)
8. Restart the service: `Start-Service -Name StateRepository`
9. Confirm it's running: `Get-Service -Name StateRepository`
10. Remove the package: `Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Where-Object { $_.Name -like '*Cortana*' } | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers`

Answer (score 1):

To add to what Girish and Dan posted above on Windows 10 Professional you can first start turning of Cortana (and related) features by typing Cortana in the search bar and then left-clicking on the Gear icon to display the settings window.

From here you can switch off various features related to Cortana (or more like opt out, they still turn back on sometimes).  However for a more substantial move I recommend doing the following:

1. Press Windows Key + R to display the Run box Type gpedit.msc to
   start the group policy management addin
2. Left click on the folder labelled Administrative Templates to select
   it You should now see a filter icon appear on the toolbar just above
   (looks like a funnel)
3. Left-click on the menu option View > Filter Options > tick 'Enable
   Keyword Filter' to enable the text box and type **cortana** and then
   hit OK to apply the filter.
4. Expand the **Administrative Folder** and then left-click on the All
   Settings item to display all items that match the filter on the
   right.

Now you can disable all the options relating to cortana and watch your CPU cycles drop and temps return to normal!

Answer (score 0):

Install latest `winget` from https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/releases, then run:

```
winget uninstall cortana
```