# Can Cortana do things like "show hidden files" or "rename folder"?

Tags: windows-10, cortana

I have no Windows 10 yet and I'm wondering if Cortana can do some actions like:

- turn on "show hidden files" in Explorer
- select some folder and rename it
- turn off computer
- delete file

or this is just search, calendar and e-mail oriented mechanism that does few things and thats all?

I remember Vista speech recognition where I could move cursor and do a lot of things without keyboard.

Comment: Mostly just search, news, weather, other "personal assistant" type stuff. I don't think she's that capable.

Comment: So they are copying Google Now idea and looks like they abandoned (for now) Vista speech recognition that could do almost everything. That sucks.

Comment: There could be more features to come. I didn't find anything that advanced though. Everybody's trying to make their own personal assistant now.

Comment: @Kamil - I don't really see how Cortana is Microsoft copying Google on anything when Siri has been around longer then Google Now and Cortana.  I have been talking to my computer for nearly a decade using speech assistance, built right into Windows.

Comment: To be fair, you don't really want people walking past and screaming out things like "Delete current folder" or "Mark all files as hidden."

Comment: @MichaelFrank And if someone would scream something like this in my office - the next thing he would say would be "Hey Cortana, where ifs nearesft dentisft?". And I would just recover files with Shadow Copy or something. That's not a problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Cortana is a voice recognition and human interface program that Microsoft describes as "your personal assistant". When activated it links with your Microsoft Account and email Hotmail MSN Live.com and any device connected to it such as your tablet, phone, laptop, desktop,router and has full unrestricted access to all of your data.

This includes access to any and all folders public and private that stored are on you computer. It collects every password you use for all of your online activity and also has unrestricted access to all of your emails.

According to Microsoft's Privacy Policy [Cortana](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/cortana-privacy-faq) uses this information such as all of your phone contacts there names,phone numbers,home addresses,photos and voice patterns and everyone connected to every social network you use and I quote "serve you better".

It tracks your daily movements through your phone and activates on its own whenever you pass free wifi or open internet sources logging and collecting data in so that it can use the information about your daily routines so that it can generate profile in order to be your "personal assistant" that helps you manage every aspect of your life.

If this seems a bit to much then you can remove the program. Simply flipping a switch to "off" does not fully disable it. Here's how to really [disable Cortana](https://superuser.com/questions/949569/can-i-completely-disable-cortana-on-windows-10?rq=1).