# Is there a way to block Cortana's access to Outlook emails and calendar?

Tags: windows-10, cortana

I have been thinking about eventually upgrading my Windows 7 to Windows 10 but would not like Cortana to have unrestricted access to my emails (as stated in the answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/951449/can-cortana-do-things-like-show-hidden-files-or-rename-folder)) or my calendar for that matter.

There are some instructions on how to remove Cortana from the system. For example there is the selected answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/949569/can-i-completely-disable-cortana-on-windows-10) although it's updated version states "Apparently, this trick stopped working at some point". The other answers to the question also indicate varying degrees of success.

I also have the concern that if I remove it, Microsoft may reinstall it later when they push an update to the machine.

So I wanted to know if there is another alternative of allowing it to run, but without access to the emails or the calendar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Click/tap on the Cortana icon (Windows+S) on the taskbar, click/tap on the Notebook icon and click on Permissions
2. Turn On or Off the Contacts, email, calendar, & communication history permissions setting for what you want.