# How to reinstall Cortana?

Tags: windows-10, cortana

With reference to:

[Can I completely disable Cortana on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/949569/can-i-completely-disable-cortana-on-windows-10)

I removed the Cortana packages from my running Windows 10 using the method posted by magicandre1981 and using  win6x_registry_tweak.

My question is how can I re-install Cortana (or for that matter any other package removed similarly)?

I have opened up the install.wim image (converted from a Win 10 install.esd file) and found Cortana in the system apps folder, but don't know how / what to use to re-install it.

Any help please?

Comment: Did you read the last line of magicandre1981's answer? "ATTENTION. Make a full backup if you later when to restore it to get Cortana back."

Comment: Yes, I did, but that doesn't answer my question!

Comment: Yes it does. Restore from the backup you made.

Comment: Further up in the post alluded to there is a suggestion by WernerCD which uses a Powershell and:
Get-AppxPackage | Select Name, PackageFullName
Remove-AppxPackage Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_1.4.8.176_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
...which incidentally does NOT work to remove Cortana, as he would have found out by actually trying it!

However there is an 'add package' command which is the reverse of the above to add/remove individual apps like Weather, etc.

Surely there must be a similar set of tools to do the same with Cortana?

I don't care that it's gone, that's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: which version/language do you need (32 or 64Bit)?

Comment: Hi..my version is the 64 bit one. I've converted install.esd (from the Win 10 USB installer) to install.wim so I can browse it with 7Zip, and I can see the Cortana package in the system apps folder, but not sure how/what tools to use to re-install. 
Thanks.

Comment: which language? En-US?

Comment: It's EN-GB version

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: The packages are  only for 64Bit build 10240 with EN-GB MUI, if you have a newer build, this won't work. Use the [setting to disable Cortana, instead of removing Cortana!!!!!](https://superuser.com/a/1109830/174557)**

If you already removed the files, generate the CABs on your own with the [steps I posted here](https://superuser.com/a/1171910/174557). Replace Flash in the commands with Cortana. Go to the servicing\Packages folder and look for the correct names of the Cortana .mum files like here the x86 MUMs for Build 14393 [image].

Download the following 3 CAB files from my Dropbox:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dxfblnhr9b0k73m/Microsoft-Windows-Cortana-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10240.16384.cab?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/b91x0ie4j27iyfa/Microsoft-Windows-Cortana-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~en-GB~10.0.10240.16384.cab?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zcgk0wb30c178h9/Microsoft-Windows-Cortana-PAL-Desktop-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10240.16384.cab?dl=0

and store them in `C:\Cortana`.

Open a [command prompt (cmd.exe) as admin](https://superuser.com/a/497256/174557) and run this command:

```
Dism /online /Add-Package /PackagePath:C:\Cortana
```

This adds the cortana packages back to the Windows.

If you get an error message about using the 32 bit version on a 64 bit computer, instead of doing the "Dism" command in CMD, do "C:\Windows\Sysnative\dism.exe

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't doubt it will work and thank you for the commands and syntax too. What I would more like to know, is: Where, did you manage to get all those disparate files from and make them into those 3 specific packages?! Also, How did you do it?! I noticed that some of the files and folders were still in the current Win 10 installation.

Comment: I use a script to collect the files from WinSxS and put them into a CAB file. But I haven't tried if this really brings back cortana. I don't use it and have no intension to reinstall it because I use StartIsBack++ in my Windows 10 VM.

Comment: @magicandre1981 - What was the script that collected the files so those that want to collect the files themselves can do so.

Comment: The answers doesn't work for me as it's not compatible to my build version. I now switched to Classicshell as it brings back the search functionality and that's actually all I use the start menu for. http://www.classicshell.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3449

Comment: @fivef yes, this is for Build 10240 (July 2015 version). If you use 1511 it doesn't work.

Comment: Where did you find these cab files? I have 1 computer that works and 1 that doesn't. If I knew where they came from, I could pull them from the working machine with 1511

Comment: @Randy I exported the files from WinSxS on a VM running Build 10240

Comment: This is version-specific. For me, it fails with error `The package Microsoft-Windows-Cortana-Package is not applicable to the image. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_ProcessPackageChange`

Comment: @b1nary.atr0phy yes, those packages are for the 64 Bit RTM Build 10240 for English International (UK) and don't work with Version 1511 or 1607

Comment: Where can I get a new version of these packages for Windows 10 v1607?

Comment: @Yovav - Use the script to extract the files yourself.

Comment: The script is going through 3 steps and finishes, then I'm getting Error: 0x800f081e - The specified package is not applicable to this image.

Comment: Your trying to extract your package for the correct region, in any event, your request for help within a comment is out of scope.  If you have a specific question on how to do this, ask a question, so a proper answer can be composed.

Comment: @Yovav as I said this is for Build 10240. if you use Win10 1607, you need to extract the data from the mounted WIM.

Answer (score 0):

Running System File Checker fixed this problem for me after I deleted Cortana. This can be done by running the following command on an Administrator Command Prompt

```
sfc /scannow
```

Answer (score 0):

If you save this as a .reg file and double click it, it works for me (assuming you TURNED OFF cortana instead of destroying the files. See also this gui: https://superuser.com/a/1196624/234051

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Search]
"AllowCortana"=dword:00000001
"AllowCortanaAboveLock"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search]
"CortanaConsent"=dword:00000001
"AllowSearchToUseLocation"=dword:00000001
"BingSearchEnabled"=dword:00000001
```