# Cortana doesn't work after BSOD

Tags: windows-10, cortana

I had a BSOD, so I forcibly shut down my PC. When I restarted it, it took some time to install a few Windows update; then the `%temp%` path was changed and I had to change it back.

Before I restarted my PC, Cortana searching from the Start menu wasn't working, and it didn't work after I set back my temp directory.

When I try to run Cortana it doesn't launch at all; nothing happens. It doesn't appear in the Task Manager window, and the search bar in the Start menu isn't activated.

Searching itself is working. I can search in any place rather than the start menu.

I've tried to restore Cortana using [magicandre1981](https://superuser.com/questions/963064/how-to-reinstall-cortana) answer but I didn't work either.

How can I make Cortana work again?

Comment: Did you try and open up cmd.exe and running the command `sfc /scannow` This will check if there are any corrupted file system files and may get cortana working again for you. Let me know if it does not help.

Comment: I've tried it (sorry for the late reply). It says there is a corrupted file and windows couldn't solve them.

Comment: it's fine see if anything in this [Link](http://www.howtogeek.com/222532/how-to-repair-corrupted-windows-system-files-with-the-sfc-and-dism-commands/) can help you repair the currupted files.

Comment: I had to install a new windows version (comes with the updates) to fix the problem. But yes I tried  `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` and sfc /scannow. None of them solves the problem. Classic Windows crap.