# Messed up, need to reinstall Cortana and the Start-menu Search

Tags: windows-10, reinstall, cortana

I was a *complete* idiot and used [this](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-uninstall-and-remove-cortana-in-windows-10/) without realising it would remove the start-menu search. (I know there's a warning, I just saw the download link and clicked it without thinking. Very stupid of me.) While Classic Shell works okay as an alternative, I miss certain features of the original Windows Search. I'd be ***incredibly grateful*** if someone could help me re-install Cortana (and the Windows Search).

Many thanks in advance.

([This](https://superuser.com/questions/963064/how-to-reinstall-cortana) didn't work.)

Comment: If this does not turn out well, try looking at a start menu like Classic Shell with a custom icon. I hope someone with a bit more knowledge will come to help.

Comment: @Tealkine Thanks for the response; I am currently using Classic Shell but I miss the standard Windows Search. If nobody is able to find a solution, Classic Shell will work, but it really bugs me that I don't have the original search anymore.

Comment: You will have to reinstall Windows, the method you used, prevents you from enabling it any other way.

Comment: I wonder if a restore point (Windows Restore) will fix it

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this problem myself.

Right click on 'Start'

command prompt (admin)

```
SFC /scannow
```

this will fix any missing / corrupted component in your windows 10.
It will take ~10 min to complete.

hope this help.