# Replace cortana icon with search icon in Windows 10 v1607

Tags: windows-10, search, icons, cortana, windows-10-v1607

I had the previous version of Windows 10 with Cortana disabled. Therefore, in the taskbar I had a loupe icon instead of the Cortana one.

Then I installed the Anniversary Update (v1607). For some reason, this replaced the loupe with the Cortana icon on all my computers.

Strangely, on my desktop PC, the icon was eventually automatically changed back to the loupe, like I want.

[image: Loupe icon]

But my laptop still has the Cortana icon. I want to replace it with the loupe icon.

[image: Cortana icon]

How can I do that manually?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To [disable Cortana](http://winaero.com/blog/disable-cortana-in-windows-10-anniversary-update-version-1607/) and get the old search icon back, start regedit.exe, go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Search`, create a new `32-bit DWORD` value here named `AllowCortana` and leave its value data as 0.

[image]

After a reboot you see the Cortana Logo is gone and the local search opens:

[image]

Since Windows 10 v1803 (Build 17134) you also need to add the DWORD `BingSearchEnabled` and `CortanaConsent` to `0` under the mentioned key.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search]
"BingSearchEnabled"=dword:00000000
"CortanaConsent"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: I was going to test this, but when I turned on my laptop I already had the loupe, no idea why. Thanks anyway.

Comment: have you used any tweaking tool, maybe it sets the same value

Comment: For me the 'Windows Search' key was not yet present in the regedit Windows folder. Just creted the key and the AllowCortana value.

Comment: When after the reboot the Search button is missing, right click the taskbar and choose Search > Show search icon.

Comment: I just saw this problem appear after an update, and now, I can't find the "Windows Search" folder at the end. Is it the end of normal search?

Comment: @MrBrody create the key if it is not there.

Answer (score -2):

I have been able to test with another computer, and the solution is easy: **restart the PC**.

I have read Cortana is almost mandatory in the Anniversary Update. So probably this only worked because Cortana is not available for my language.

Otherwise, it seems I would have need to edit the registry as magicandre1981 [explained](https://superuser.com/a/1109830/186753).

Comment: This would better serve the community as a comment.  "I have read Cortana is almost mandatory in the Anniversary Update." - I don't know what you read but it isn't correct.

Comment: @Ramhound It's an answer because restarting the PC worked for me. With "almost mandatory" I meant it doesn't seem to be any easy way (e.g. without messing with the registry) to disable Cortana.

Comment: You have never been able to disable Cortana, on Windows 10, without jumping through hoops though.  Only the very early versions, of Windows 10, before July 2015 had ways to do it.

Comment: @Ramhound I believe there was a checkbox to disable Cortana before the anniversary update. But my case may be different because as I said Cortana is not available for my language.