# How do I enable Cortana after the Anniversary Update (1607)?

Tags: cortana, windows-10-v1607

The Windows 10 Anniversary Update appears to have killed Cortana. How do I bring her back?

The search screen is the old, standard one, and the search icon is a magnifying glass instead of the Cortana circle.

[image]

Cortana settings let me choose language but reports a region mismatch even though both are the same. There are no other Cortana-specific options there.

[image]

Comment: do the opposite from here: http://superuser.com/a/1109830/174557

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to a [Microsoft Answers thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_cortana/can-no-longer-use-cortana-after-update-to-1607/cd2a6514-e566-492d-9b44-ad0bf0ee1856)

The registry value `BingSearchEnabled` in the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search` needs to be set to `1`.

Run the following in `cmd`:

```
reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search /f /v BingSearchEnabled /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

Or use `regedit` to navigate to the same key and set the value.

---

I suspect this specifically affects those who updated from a system where they had web search disabled. If you wish to continue using Cortana, apparently you must enable that option now.

Comment: Of course, this also opens up a rather interesting method to disable Cortana - at least until MS fixes the bug.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem here.

```
Get-AppXPackage -Name Microsoft.Windows.Cortana | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

this powershell command worked for me.