# Win 10 Remove cortana but not search windows feature?

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, cortana

Is there a way to remove the cortana application but leave the search bar that is the replacement to cortana?

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you using?  Version 1607 change the interaction between Cortana and Search in Windows 10.  What is possible, would be described, in [Can I completely disable Cortana on Windows 10?](http://superuser.com/questions/949569/can-i-completely-disable-cortana-on-windows-10)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace cortana icon with search icon in Windows 10 v1607](http://superuser.com/questions/1109804/replace-cortana-icon-with-search-icon-in-windows-10-v1607)

Answer (score -1):

No You can dis able Cortona in the settings but that will also remove the search bar from the desktop. You will still have it in the start menu like it was in Windows 7.

Comment: Third-party tools such as ShutUp10 do a fairly good job of disabling most Cortana "features" such as voice recognition, and do not disable Search. They do *not* disable all Cortana processes, though. You can disable microphone usage by applications, though, until needed.

Comment: "dis able Cortona in the settings" And how exactly to do so?