# Packaging / Extracting Windows 10 Native Flash Player

Tags: windows-10, flash, flash-player, dism

To make a very long story short:  Someone #@%@ed up and there are several Windows 10 assets in my environment that require Flash OCX repair (IT WASN'T ME!)

Simply re-registering the OCX modules doesn't entirely resolve the issue, even after completely removing ownership from the built-in application itself (several keys return ACCESS DENIED when regsvr32 tries to access them).

I've decided that uninstall / reinstall Windows 10 Native Flash Player (ActiveX) on the deployed Windows 10 assets.  Using a DISM.EXE method similar to the one found at [this blog](https://eksith.wordpress.com/2015/08/06/how-to-remove-flash-from-windows-10/), I've scripted the uninstall routine.  However, I'm looking for a "light-weight" method of reinstalling it.  Any suggestions?  I'd prefer not to have to mount an entire image to each machine (I'm looking at SMS / SCUP deployment for this solution).  Is there a way to, say, isolate the Windows 10 Flash Player application on an image file, extract it (say to a .WIM file), and then point DISM to it?

Thank you!

Comment: for which Windows 10 build and architecture (32 or 64bit) do you need them?

Comment: Windows 10 Enterprise 64-Bit.   I'm also curious if there is a way to generate, say, a .CAB file from an online image that has Flash installed.

Comment: I posted some steps to extract the data.

Comment: any update on your question? Does it work? Or does it fail?

Answer (score 2):

1. Download [sxsextract](http://www74.zippyshare.com/v/WL5IczN5/file.html) to `C:\Extractor\`
2. Mount the Windows 10 `Install.wim` to `C:\Extractor\Mount`

   `Dism /Mount-Image /ImageFile:C:\Extractor\ISO\install.wim /index:1 /MountDir:C:\Extractor\Mount`
3. Use [ProcessHacker to open a cmd.exe as TrustedInstaller](http://wj32.org/processhacker/forums/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=2407)

   [image]
4. Inside the cmd.exe, run `cd \Extractor` `ENTER` to go to `C:\Extractor\`
5. run the 2 commands to extract the Flash Data into a CAB:

   `cscript.exe sxsextract.vbs /Debug /VICIOUSHACKS /Image:C:\Extractor\Mount\Windows C:\Extractor\Mount\Windows\servicing\Packages\Adobe-Flash-For-Windows-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.14393.0.mum Adobe-Flash-For-Windows-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.14393.0.cab`

   `cscript.exe sxsextract.vbs /Debug /VICIOUSHACKS /Image:C:\Extractor\Mount\Windows C:\Extractor\Mount\Windows\servicing\Packages\Adobe-Flash-For-Windows-onecoreuap-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.14393.0.mum Adobe-Flash-For-Windows-onecoreuap-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.14393.0.cab`
6. Unmount the `install.wim`

   `Dism /Unmount-Image /MountDir:C:\Extractor\Mount /discard`
7. Now use `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:<PathToCABfiles>` on the damaged systems to restore the Flash files.

This restores the 2 Flash Packages. This is for 64Bit Build 14393, the Windows 10 Anniversary update. Change the names according to the Build you use.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the write up.  Will try this weekend and let you know how it turns out!

Comment: Hello, MagicAndre.  Sorry if I'm just not seeing it, but how, exactly, do I download sxsextract?  I'm not seeing a download link and the code within the document doesn't appear to be a VBS script, as far as I can tell.

Comment: you need to register in that forum to get the download link