# DISM Error: 0x800f0805

Tags: windows-7, dism

I was removing some packages in offline mode from Windows 7 HomePremium X64 image and I received this error on some of them.

```
DISM v6.1.7600.16385
Error: 0x800f0805
The specified package is not valid windows package.
```

Examples:

```
Microsoft-Windows-Shell-MultiplayerInboxGames-Package~31bf3856ad3
64e35~amd64~en-US~6.1.7601.17514

Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-Optional-Package~31bf3856ad364
e35~amd64~en-US~8.0.7601.17514

Microsoft-Windows-MediaCenter-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~en-U
S~6.1.7601.17514
```

Does it mean that they're not in the image?

Comment: "Does it mean that they're not in the image?" - You would have to run the command that lists the packages contain on the image.   We can't answer your question without that information.

Comment: They are in the list, of course.

Comment: If you know they are part of the image, then why are you asking, if they are part of your image?

Comment: how have you removed/tried to remove them?

Comment: Hey guys, when I open a thread here I expect to receive smart answers or I would open the thread on Technet...
Why do I ask if these packages are in the wim file?
Because Microsoft tells me that they are not valid (I don't know what they mean).

Comment: How do I remove them? DISM!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't remove them directly. There is some work in the registry required to  make them visible to DISM. There is already a tool which does it for you.

It is called [install_wim_tweak.exe](http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=152688).

Open a [cmd.exe as admin](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813(v=ws.10).aspx) and run `install_wim_tweak.exe /o /l` to dump all available packages into the `Packages.txt`. Open it to see the name of all packages and run `install_wim_tweak.exe /o /c Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-Optional-Package /r` to kill IE.

Comment: Ah, at last we understand each other. Thanks. I used that tool only to see the packages list, then I switched to DISM (useless tool)... another Microsoft epic fail.

Comment: Hey Andre, I almost forgot... sometimes it's not easy to understand what these packages are. Do you know if there's some Microsoft reference documentation? I can't find detailed info...

Comment: use this to extract the packages: http://superuser.com/a/1171910/174557 and in the CAB you see the files, now check the properties of the files, to see what the files do. now you see what the package does. now you can also create a backup and import it later back if you deleted an package that you need later again.

Comment: Beautiful, but I read that verbose post and I don't see any link to download. If you can upload that tool it would be nice...

Comment: register to MDL forum to see the download link

Comment: I know it, but there's nothing to download...

Comment: I shared the file: http://www74.zippyshare.com/v/WL5IczN5/file.html

Comment: Hey andre, does it work?... this software I mean... install_wim_tweak.exe. It says all the packages were correctly removed (offline mount), but the image size doesn't change and when I install the system they are all there... I'm just a bit ?????

Comment: Also, I downloaded the latest available version (1.4.8 for netfx 4.6.1).

Comment: rebuild the WIM by exporting the edition to a new WIM