# Removing packages from Windows 7 x64 using win6x_registry_tweak

Tags: windows-7, deployment

I was suggested to use this software to remove certain packages from a Windows 7 x64 (as I had some problems with DISM: [DISM Error: 0x800f0805](https://superuser.com/questions/1183258/dism-error-0x800f0805)).
The program seems to work properly, it claims to have removed the packages, but actually the packages are still present in the image.

EDIT.

Ok, I did some tests in a VM (Win7x64Sp1 installed) removing packages from install.wim /index:2 (Windows 7 HomePremium).

Here are the conclusions:

-the program works with NetFx v3

-there's a version specifically done for NetFx 4.6.1, but it doesn't work with NetFx 4.6.2

-there are three packages that cannot be removed or win6x_registry_tweak goes into an error loop (something like error 50 in DISM).
These packages are:

Windows Foundation Package

Windows ProfessionalEdition wrapper

Windows UltimateEdition wrapper

-the removal of some other packages it breaks Windows setup. They are:

Windows Client Language Pack

Windows Client Drivers

Windows Common Drivers

I hope this can help you. :)

Comment: rebuild the WIM. but after installing the packages should be automatically removed.

Comment: What exactly is your question.  Edit your question, you should specifically, state what your question

Comment: Ramhound, you never understand anything - as usual. What is exactly your function? Andre, I committed, saved, exported, ran as admin but the packages are still there. Please explain the procedure you follow.

Comment: I read a few threads about this tool; unfortunately it is totally unreliable, many people have experienced problems.

Comment: @M4RK77 If your going make a rude statement like that I can't help.  My function is I want to help you by submitting an answer to your question

Comment: @M4RK77 -  **I have never issued a vote to this question.**  You should spend some time and format your question.  *There was only a single revision of this question until a few minutes ago.*  In order to put the record straight, out of all the undeleted questions you have, I have issued a vote to just one of them.  [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1086596/what-services-sysprep-needs-to-run)

Comment: I will say the following the nicest way I know how.  Voting is anonymous.  Calling people out, on how they vote, is not constructive.  You should focus on improving your questions, consider this fact, a single upvote can counter 5 downvotes...Out of all your questions that have not been deleted, you have only recieved, 2 downvotes and only one of those were mine.

Comment: What I don't understand is why you and all these other guys continue to delete my comments and leave yours... It's really pathetic...

Comment: @M4RK77 - If your comments are being removed by a moderator, its because somebody has flagged them, and a moderator that handled the flag didn't feel they were constructive.  I will be more then happy to delete my own comments if that will make you feel better.  At the end of the day, I have better things to do then target somebody like you, if you contribute something and I leave a comment directed towards you, it's because I focus on the review queue.

Answer (score 0):

This is how servicing stack works. Sometime it needs a running (/Online) windows to remove/install packages. Or you missed to commit the changes you made to the install.wim while unmounting the WIM with DISM.

I always use [Setupcomplete.cmd](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766314.aspx) under `DVDRoot\sources\$OEM$\$$\Setup\Scripts\` to remove components:

```
@echo off

for %%i in (C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do if exist %%i:\sources\install.wim set CDROM=%%i:

REG ADD HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnceEx

SET KEY=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnceEx
SET D=%CDROM%\updates
SET Registry=%CDROM%\Registry

REG ADD %KEY% /V TITLE /D "Remove Windows Packages" /f

REG ADD %KEY%\008 /VE /D "remove Windows Packages" /f
REG ADD %KEY%\008 /V 1 /D "%Windir%\Setup\Scripts\install_wim_tweak.exe /o /c Microsoft-Windows-OpticalMediaDisc-Package /r" /f
REG ADD %KEY%\008 /V 2 /D "%Windir%\Setup\Scripts\install_wim_tweak.exe /o /c Microsoft-Windows-Tuner-Drivers-Package /r" /f
REG ADD %KEY%\008 /V 3 /D "%Windir%\Setup\Scripts\install_wim_tweak.exe /o /c Microsoft-Windows-SUA-Package /r" /f
REG ADD %KEY%\008 /V 4 /D "%Windir%\Setup\Scripts\install_wim_tweak.exe /o /c Microsoft-Windows-SNMP-Package /r" /f 
REG ADD %KEY%\008 /V 5 /D "%Windir%\Setup\Scripts\install_wim_tweak.exe /o /c Microsoft-Hyper-V /r" /f 

REG ADD %KEY%\908 /VE /D "Reboot PC..." /f
REG ADD %KEY%\908 /V 2 /D "shutdown -r -t 0" /f

EXIT
```

Comment: Andre, as I said I committed the changes... I can't do much more. I didn't try the online mode, but I don't see the utility. At this point, I prefer to use programs like WinReducer and get rid of all the garbage contained in this system.

Comment: those tools simply delete the files/registry entries, but don't uninstall the packages correctly. use the setupcomplete way

Comment: Are you sure??? The authors say it removes packages: http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/152688-win6x_registry_tweak/. Anyway, I see a .NET v4.6.1 version, probably the old version didn't work correctly with netfx update; I have v4.6.2 installed, maybe that's my problem... What version you have on your system?

Comment: I talk about this reducer tool, this deletes file. this WIM tools removes them correctly.

Comment: Andre, I'm sorry if I'm bothering you, but I cannot find a way to make this program works. I tried to remove some packages online, I restarted and checked the list of packages and they're still there. Which system do you use (7,8,10) and what version of netfx have you installed?

Comment: this is unrelated to .net version. I use the old for 3.5 and on win8/10 I use a .config file which forces to use .net 4.x runtime. if you run the commands in the setupcomplete it works! I use this for years. YOU DO SOMETHING WRONG! And becasue you have no idea, you should stop at that point

Comment: So unrelated that they did a specific version for NET 4.6.1 (that doesn't work for 4.6.2, but I don't want to downgrade). Ok genius, I stop at that point... :)

Comment: if you would run it exactly as written it would work.

Comment: for me it always works. again, you do something wrong all the time