# Does Windows 10 Pro N not include Microsoft bloatware like Candy Crush?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-installation, bloatware

I installed a both Windows 10 Pro, and Windows 10 N Pro.  According to [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3133719/media-feature-pack-for-n-editions-of-windows-10-version-1607)

> The "N" editions of Windows 10 include the same functionality as other
>   editions of Windows 10 except for media-related technologies. The N
>   editions don't include Windows Media Player, Skype, or certain
>   preinstalled media apps (Music, Video, Voice Recorder).

I noticed that in the N install that Candy Crush and associated "Bloatware" were not installed.

Is this true that the N version will not install the extra apps?  In the list provided by Microsoft [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3133719/media-feature-pack-for-n-editions-of-windows-10-version-1607), apps like Candy Crush are not mentioned.  If you install the Media Feature Pack update package, would these apps be added back?

Answer (score 2):

It still includes the Blotaware apps, because the ContentDeliveryManager-Package (`Microsoft-Windows-ContentDeliveryManager-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~10.0.17134.1.mum`) is still included in the N Edition.

You can use the [setupcomplete.cmd](https://superuser.com/a/1189930/174557) during setup to remove the package and look if this prevents installing bloatware.

```
install_wim_tweak.exe /o /c Microsoft-Windows-ContentDeliveryManager-Package /r
```

Answer (score 1):

> If you install the Media Feature Pack update package, would these apps be added back?

The Windows 10 Media Feature Pack does not install Candy Crush.