# Can't get Windows Search nor Cortana back

Tags: windows-10, search, cortana

I followed this guide in order to remove Cortana: 
https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-uninstall-and-remove-cortana-in-windows-10/

But now, when I open windows menu, the search doesn't work, nor can I get cortana back.

I factory resetted windows from scratch TWICE, but none of them work anymore, even when I check "use cortana" at the blue screen setting. (I see the cortana search window but it is disabled, But not the notebook)

Comment: Follow my answer in the duplicate. I've [posted here](https://superuser.com/a/1171910/174557) how to extract the files into CABs. Do this for Cortana. look into the mount folder **C:\Extractor\Mount\Windows\servicing\Packages** for the compete Cortana names.

Comment: Hi magicandre, I don't have "Extractor" in C, should I create one? I got a laptop, where do I have the windows install.wim?

Comment: follow my link: https://superuser.com/a/1171910/174557