# How do I Uninstall/Disable unnecessary Microsoft applications of Windows 10?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, performance, gpu

My university prohibits me using Windows Cloud storage and several its functions in Windows 10 Enterprise because it stores passwords in the cloud, prohibiting EU security legislation. I cannot understand the internals of the system. I want to minimize all its functions. I want to decrease the HDD accesses, reads and writes in my Windows 10, which is significantly greater than in Ubuntu 14* and 15*.

Too high HDD accesses make my computer noisy in running Windows 10. I cannot accept that Windows uses its P2P technology between its customers to transfer customers data without customer's acceptance. I only need Windows 10 for GPU computation by Asus GTX 9** family in Matlab so all other features are unnecessary. I have successfully uninstalled and disabled the following applications

- Skype,
- OneDrive,
- Windows store (WinStore.Mobile.exe as suspended) uninstalled by Samuel's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1021578/2005) below.

Apps left untouched in the system

- SHellExperienceHost.exe (apparently necessary)
- SearchUI.exe (Search and Cortana) - I disagreed Windows to use Cortana but it is still keeping it on as *suspended* which I do not want.

---

How can you uninstall/disable default applications of Windows 10 Enterprise?

Comment: To know how to disable "Windows Store" please take a look: http://www.zerodollartips.com/disable-windows-store-windows-8-8-1-10/

Comment: Do you have Home or Pro version? Group policies are not supported in the Home version.

Comment: `gepdit` is **not** the same as `gpedit`. You are typing the command name incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PowerShell to remove the Windows store, run the below command:

```
Get-AppxPackage *windowsstore* | Remove-AppxPackage
```

- ShellExperienceHost.exe is important and required for things like the start menu/screen to work and for app integration with the task bar.
- Unfortunately Cortana cannot be completely removed, although you can [perform a hack](https://superuser.com/questions/949569/can-i-completely-disable-cortana-on-windows-10) to disable it almost completely, (*at the risk of breaking your start/search bar)*
- Search is integral to Windows and links in to indexing etc... Not sure why you would want to remove it, unless I've misunderstood what you meant.

Comment: Excellent answer about those applications! Is there any other ways to uninstall other software than are not needed for the GPU computation. I just want to decrease HDD reads/writes by the OS.

Comment: Can you please explain the part `*windowsstore*` of your command? I have a difficulty in understanding the stars.

Comment: There's always going to be the limitation that you're using a heavily consumer focused, someone "bloated" operating system designed to be feature reach and easy to use etc... The only thing I would suggest is right clicking each of the apps  on the start screen and selecting "uninstall" where available.

Comment: Is there any way of doing it more scientific computation oriented? I just need the GPU computation because the system has most stable drivers of Nvidia for CUDA computation.

Comment: If you're using the GPU for computation, I would of thought that simply stripping unwanted applications of the machine would suffice? If after all you're not using the CPU?

Comment: Your point is valid. I need to monitor your point closely when implementing my setting. I have not managed to run at all GPU 9** family in Linux PCs. I need to get some results in both systems, and with Windows, I have managed to get further.

Comment: How do you reinstall windowsstore? Something like Get-AppxPackage *windowstore* | Install-AppxPackage?

Answer (score 1):

You should check out windows 10 LTSB release, which doesn't include: Store; Cortana; Edge; etc.  It also doesn't get the update version pushed out via windows update.  You get the decided when you want to install those major updates...download and install them on your own time.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-10-enterprise

Comment: Why it does not get an update pushed out via Windows Update?