# How to re-enable Cortana Windows 10, used adding .bak to file folder to disable

Tags: windows-10, cortana

I followed the steps listed by MC10 in this link [Can I completely disable Cortana on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/949569/can-i-completely-disable-cortana-on-windows-10)

But then I realized it disables being able to search using the start menu and I want to re-enable Cortana.  I tried deleting the .bak from the file folder, but I can't because Windows created a new identical folder.  I tried removing the new folder and removing .bak, restart, no luck and then I also just got rid of the old .bak folder, restart no luck.

How can I get Cortana working again?

Comment: If your running Version 1511 you can't, the commands you would need to use, are not working the current build.  You approached disabling Cortana the incorrect way sadly

Comment: So am I just out of luck other than doing a clean install?

Comment: Hey, did you find a method to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've done it. 
I had two files Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy.bak ( * first step * remove .bak put in a z )and Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy  ( after the first step put a Z )
I removde .bak from the first one and put a z at the end. Same for the other one put a Z and then it should have merged, just remove the z and you're good to go.

Comment: Hey, can you please update your answer. I doubt if it will work today too.