# Remove Unwanted Metro Apps from Windows 10 All Apps List

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, modern-ui

For conventional desktop applications such as chrome or office, we can remove the shortcuts from `all apps` list by `right clicking on the icon`, selecting `more`, clicking on `open file location` and then deleting the `start menu shotcut`.

But the same procedure does not work for `modern/metro apps`.There are few Windows 10 metro apps like `cortana` or `contact support` or `windows feedback` which I never use and these apps can not be uninstalled at all.

So I would know if there is a way to remove these apps from `all apps` list (since it is not possible to uninstall them) or are we locked down even for this simple thing.

Comment: Are you asking how you uninstall Cortana or asking how to remove those from your applications list, despite specifically viewing a list, of all installed applications?

Comment: If you dislike how WIndows 10 start menu works, the only solution I know outside of removing those applications, is to use a program to modify the behavior of the start menu itself.

Answer (score 3):

To remove all such applications ONLY from your user account (and to not delete something important!), use this command in PowerShell:

```
Get-AppxPackage |
Where-Object Name -notlike *Libs* |
Where-Object Name -notlike *Native* |
Where-Object Name -ne Microsoft.WindowsStore |
Where-Object Name -ne Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller |
Where-Object Name -ne Microsoft.StorePurchaseApp |
Where-Object Name -ne Microsoft.AccountsControl |
Where-Object Name -ne Microsoft.BioEnrollment |
Where-Object Name -ne Microsoft.CredDialogHost |
Where-Object Name -ne Microsoft.LockApp |
Where-Object Name -ne Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge |
Where-Object Name -ne windows.immersivecontrolpanel |
Where-Object Name -notlike *Windows.* |
Where-Object Name -ne c5e2524a-ea46-4f67-841f-6a9465d9d515 |
Where-Object Name -ne 1527c705-839a-4832-9118-54d4Bd6a0c89 |
Where-Object Name -ne DesktopView |
Where-Object Name -ne E2A4F912-2574-4A75-9BB0-0D023378592B |
Where-Object Name -ne EnvironmentsApp |
Where-Object Name -notlike *Microsoft.Services.Store* |
Where-Object Name -notlike Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin* |
Where-Object Name -notlike Microsoft.Win32WebViewHost* |
Where-Object Name -notlike Microsoft.XboxGameCallableUI* |
Where-Object Name -notlike Microsoft.PPIProjection* |
Where-Object Name -notlike Microsoft.MicrosoftEdgeDevToolsClient* |
Where-Object Name -notlike Microsoft.ECApp* |
Where-Object Name -notlike Microsoft.AsyncTextService* |
Where-Object Name -notlike InputApp* |
Where-Object Name -notlike F46D4000-FD22-4DB4-AC8E-4E1DDDE828FE* |
Remove-AppxPackage
```

Don't worry, in case if you want to get them back, they are not lost - you can find them all in the Store application and redownload them.

But with each new user theese applications will be automatically installed in their profile. To avoid that and get rid of these "provisioned applications" completely, use this command:

```
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online |
Where-Object DisplayName -ne Microsoft.StorePurchaseApp |
Where-Object DisplayName -ne Microsoft.WindowsStore |
Where-Object DisplayName -ne Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller |
Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage -Online
```

The same rule applies - if you want to get the application back - just install it through the Store.

Comment: As time passes by, some more libs are to be excluded from removing because they are essential part of Windows:

Comment: You may want to add the following: `Where-Object Name -notlike Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin* |
Where-Object Name -notlike Microsoft.Win32WebViewHost* |
Where-Object Name -notlike Microsoft.XboxGameCallableUI* |
Where-Object Name -notlike Microsoft.PPIProjection* |
Where-Object Name -notlike Microsoft.MicrosoftEdgeDevToolsClient* |
Where-Object Name -notlike Microsoft.ECApp* |
Where-Object Name -notlike Microsoft.AsyncTextService* |
Where-Object Name -notlike InputApp* |
Where-Object Name -notlike F46D4000-FD22-4DB4-AC8E-4E1DDDE828FE* |`

Answer (score 1):

It's not shortcut, but the real application icons on All app menu.

You can only uninstall it to remove from start menu.

In addition, you can find all applications under this folder:

```
explorer.exe shell:Appsfolder
```

Answer (score 0):

The built-in accessories apps that come along with Windows 10 and found in Start menu such as Maps, Money, Calculator ...etc. Can be uninstalled by right-click on the app tile on Start menu, and choosing uninstall. IF you cannot uninstall it from the Start menu, then uninstall them from `Uninstall or change a program` feature or use a third-party tool like [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner). I use it personally, and I uninstalled all those programs never had a problem in that.

As of Cortana and Edge, you will have to uninstall it via Powershell.

[Uninstalling Cortana](https://superuser.com/questions/949569/can-i-completely-disable-cortana-on-windows-10)

[Uninstalling Edge](https://superuser.com/questions/949814/how-to-disable-or-uninstall-microsoft-edge-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 0):

On  the Settings app and click “Apps & features”. This lists your apps and programs and tells you how much space each is taking up. Click on a program you don’t want and you may be offered the option to uninstall it.

Otherwise, Piriform’s CCleaner Free provides a simple way to remove most of the bundled apps. Run CCleaner Free and click Tools (the spanner icon) to get a list of programs.

Comment: Piriform has in the past been compromised.  CCleaner in the past was accidentally distributed as malware.  Piriform cannot be trusted.