# How do I disable the background process of Cortana in Windows 10 without hurting Search

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, cortana

I don't mind if Cortana remains available, I'm not looking for uninstall, I just want to **permanently disable the background process** of it (as an administrator) in a way where Windows Search (start menu and file) is still functioning.

It is possible somehow? Basically, I just want to continue using search but without the the background process of Cortana.

Answer (score -1):

i think this case below could be helpful to your scenario, kindly have a look.

[Can I completely disable Cortana on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/949569/can-i-completely-disable-cortana-on-windows-10)

Comment: Could you please copy the main points of that article in your answer in case the article disappears?

Comment: Link-only answers are not helpful.

Comment: none of those ideas working, either got fixed by MS or break search.