# not using cortana, but cortana's using ram

Tags: windows-10, memory, cortana

I disabled Cortana in Windows 10, however when I opened the Task Manager I found that Cortana was still using a good chunk of my memory. Is this a problem, and can I stop the process without harming my computer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I completely disable Cortana on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/949569/can-i-completely-disable-cortana-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 2):

What you see is the `SearchUI.exe` which also displays the search results if you don't use Cortana. You can use [WPR/xerf/WPA to track its memory usage](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-154-Memory-Footprint-and-Leaks) and look for what it allocates memory. But you can't really change it.

Comment: I can remove it (it doesn't stop me) but it keeps coming back.

Comment: again, this is the normal search of Windows 10 that can't be really disabled