# How to access the data stored by Cortana in the notebook?

Tags: windows, windows-10, privacy, cortana

Microsoft says that Cortana collects and stores data in the cloud and in the notebook, so is the data stored in the notebook are on my hard drive? and if yes how can I access them and delete them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On their servers it is under Bing settings page you can clear gathered data.  First thing you are going to want to do is stop the data gathering by Cortana, or there is no point clearing anything:  http://www.windowscentral.com/how-turn-cortana-and-stop-personal-data-gathering-windows-10

If you are wanting to totally disable Cortana see:  [Can I completely disable Cortana on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/949569/can-i-completely-disable-cortana-on-windows-10)

Comment: So no data is stored locally on my hard drive?