# Why does windows not let me to uninstall some apps?

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, default-settings, control-panel

I'm running Windows 10. I've found that `uninstall` button is grayed out for some apps at Start > Settings > System > Apps & features. Which means I can't uninstall such apps. For example here is a screen-shot for Movies & TV app which I want to uninstall:

> [image]

So, why is Windows not letting me uninstalling some apps? Are those apps essential to have or without which Windows may not work?

And how do I uninstall those apps that I feel no need and want to uninstall? I've also tried Control panel but it doesn't list those apps at Control Panel > Programs & Features > Uninstall a program.

Comment: I gave an answer to this question, but this should have been something very easy for you to find with a quick google search. Make sure you always do thorough research before posting a question.

Comment: Note that MS update *will* reinstall all the default-install apps that you uninstall periodically (during their bigger package updates).

Comment: the inbox apps are protected from uninstall since v1607. Try the hack from [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1222890/174557) in the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall these from an administrative powershell. A good reference can be found [here](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/uninstall-restore-windows-10-builtin-apps)

For example to uninstall the Movies and Tv app the command should be

`Get-AppxPackage *zunevideo* | Remove-AppxPackage`

You just have to know the name of the package for the app you want to uninstall, which you can google or find in the link I gave.

As for why they don't have uninstall as a menu option is simply Microsoft not wanting you to uninstall them, they are not necessary for your computer.