# How to Uninstall WordPad Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, wordpad

WordPad some how became my default application to open .docx files. I know I could just change the default, but, I wanted to make it be gone forever and never have the possibility of annoying me again. But.... there doesnt seem to be a way to uninstall it.

I've looked in:

- Control Panel > Uninstall a Program
- Settings > Apps & Features
- Search > WordPad > right click (there is no uninstall in the context menu)
- saw this: [Why does windows not let me to uninstall some apps?](https://superuser.com/questions/1231737/why-does-windows-not-let-me-to-uninstall-some-apps) but also did not work

Please help me escape Microsoft's iron fist.

Comment: Do note, 'tis complicated, but I have posted an answer that will work

Comment: WordPad is an operating system component. If you don’t want it, don’t use Windows. Windows may be wonky at times when it comes to file associations. No need to get all worked up.

Comment: @DanielB  "If you don’t want it, don’t use Windows. "??? So passive aggressive. If I don't want to use Word Pad, I will figure out how to destroy it, and continue using Windows, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

***Under no circumstances should you ever tamper with an operating system's native files,***

However I too hate the Windows Wordpad bs, so here's my fix. Navigate to

```
C:\Windows\write.exe
```

And delete the file. Then also navigate to

```
C:\Program Files\windows nt\accessories
```

And delete both `wordpad.exe` and `WordpadFilter.dll` (might be a good idea to delete the en-US folder as well)

***EDIT:*** Some folders worth deleting:

```
C:\Windows\WinSxS\wow64_microsoft-windows-wordpad_(blah)
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-wordpad_(blah)
C:\Windows\WinSxS\wow64_microsoft-windows-wordpad.resources
C:\Windows\WinSxS\wow64_microsoft-windows-wordpad.resources
```

***Note that to delete these files you may need to grant yourself Admin+ permissions to these files:*** To do this, follow these steps:

1. Right click the file/folder
2. Select "Properties"
3. Navigate to the "Security" Tab
4. Scroll down the "Group or user names:" list, and find:

   Users (your-desktop-name-here)
5. Take note of this group's name
6. Click advanced at the bottom of the tab
7. At the top of the page, where it says "Owner: TrustedInstaller", click Change.
8. Enter "Users", then hit  <kbd>Return</kbd>
9. Now hit apply at the bottom of the screen.
10. You can now delete the file!

Comment: Thanks D, i deleted it, despite my better judgement. But... even after restart, Word Pad still loads!!!! (and write.exe is still gone)

Comment: i have a feeling i need to delete everything named wordpad.exe

Comment: what's the worst that can happen

Comment: oh wait you updated the answer

Comment: @Andrew do let me know if this works or not. If not I'll install a Windows VM on my SSD and run a search for "wordpad" across the installation and compile a list of files to delete

Answer (score 0):

Open `Regedit.exe` and go to this key:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications

Export the branch to a .REG file.

In the right-pane, right-click `Wordpad` and choose Delete.

Windows won't associate .docx automatically with Wordpad from now on.

Note that this won't uninstall Wordpad.. only de-registers it from Default Apps.