# Error trying to uninstall universal app

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-store-app

I am trying to remove a package in windows 10 but receive the following error. I have spent some time searching on the internet but none of them have the same error as me. Please advise.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> remove-appxpackage Microsoft.Dayton.f074ae31c9_1.3160.34.2_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
remove-appxpackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CFA, Removal failed. Please contact your software vendor.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073CFA)
error 0x0: Reading manifest from location: AppxManifest.xml failed with error: The operation completed successfully.
.
NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] 1af2746e-664b-0006-4fcc-f21a4b66d501 in the Event Log or use
the command line Get-AppPackageLog -ActivityID 1af2746e-664b-0006-4fcc-f21a4b66d501
At line:1 char:1
+ remove-appxpackage Microsoft.Dayton.f074ae31c9_1.3160.34.2_x64__8weky ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (Microsoft.Dayto...__8wekyb3d8bbwe:String) [Remove-AppxPackage], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.RemoveAppxPackageCommand
```

This is not a duplicate of [Unable to uninstall Universal Apps through PowerShell](https://superuser.com/questions/1115801/unable-to-uninstall-universal-apps-through-powershell). The error message is different and my IsInbox already has a default value of 0.

I requested the log and received this. I still have no idea what is going on.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-AppPackageLog -ActivityID 03c48bb9-6706-0007-559d-c4030667d501

Time                      ID           Message
----                      --           -------
9/9/2019 8:17:11 PM       603          Started deployment Remove operation on a package with main parameter
                                       Microsoft.Dayton.f074ae31c9_1.3160.34.2_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe and Options 0 and 0.
                                       See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app
                                       deployment issues.
9/9/2019 8:17:11 PM       10002        Creating Resiliency File C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\3dbed2a1
                                       -d201-495b-b6e4-fcbcd04aade9_S-1-5-21-3890243703-3931977587-3464021798-1001_2.rs
                                       lc for Remove Operation on Package
                                       Microsoft.Dayton.f074ae31c9_1.3160.34.2_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe.
9/9/2019 8:17:11 PM       607          Deployment Remove operation on package
                                       Microsoft.Dayton.f074ae31c9_1.3160.34.2_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe has been de-queued
                                       and is running for user SID S-1-5-21-3890243703-3931977587-3464021798-1001.
9/9/2019 8:17:11 PM       402          error 0x0: Reading manifest from location: AppxManifest.xml failed with error:
                                       The operation completed successfully.
                                       .
9/9/2019 8:17:11 PM       605          The last successful state reached was BundleProcessed. Failure occurred before
                                       reaching the next state Indexed. hr: 0x80070490
9/9/2019 8:17:11 PM       401          Deployment DeStage operation with target volume C: on Package
                                       Microsoft.Dayton.f074ae31c9_1.3160.34.2_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe from:   failed with
                                       error 0x80070490. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help
                                       diagnosing app deployment issues.
9/9/2019 8:17:11 PM       404          AppX Deployment operation failed for package
                                       Microsoft.Dayton.f074ae31c9_1.3160.34.2_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe with error
                                       0x80073CFA. The specific error text for this failure is: error 0x0: Reading
                                       manifest from location: AppxManifest.xml failed with error: The operation
                                       completed successfully.
```

Comment: no one has a solution ?

Comment: ok i will also put up a bounty