# How to solve Cortana issue

Tags: windows-10, cortana

I have a Cortana problem. I disabled Cortana from gpedit; then I wanted it back I did restore the change in gpedit but I still have only the Windows search box shown below:
[image]
I tried everything found in the Internet but I still have the problem.

Is there a way I can restore Cortana?

Comment: Uhhhh, ***yes,*** [you can](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-turn-off-cortana-windows-10) @Ramhound ?????

Comment: Try this : https://superuser.com/q/949569/726810

Comment: i want to restore it not deleting it