# How to stop Cortana from running in the background?

Tags: windows-10, memory, windows-registry, regedit, cortana

Cortana continues to consume RAM and processing speed on my PC. I have disabled Cortana with RegEdit  {HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows} change 1 to 0. Even after this, I still find Cortana in my Task Manager as active as always. I try to "End Task" but Cortana immediately comes back. Any suggestions?

[image: Screenshot of CPU activity even after disabling Cortana]

Edition: Windows 10 Home
Version: 1903
Installed on: 8/23/2019
OS build: 18362.295
64-bit Operating System

Update: last few times I've checked it has remained in the green leaf econo symbol icon and stayed fixed at zero CPU usage zero memory usage (see next screenshot). However, that does not leave me reassured that it will stay like that perpetually.

[image: Cortana while in econo mode (green leaf)]

Comment: “Cortana continues to gobble away at my RAM and processing speed.” And how exactly did you determine that? Please provide a screenshot, if possible.

Comment: Okay. Screenshot added. ^_^

Comment: Edit your question to indicate what version of Windows 10 you are using

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I completely disable Cortana on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/949569/can-i-completely-disable-cortana-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Cortana (up to Windows 10 v. 1809) includes Windows Search. You *can* completely disable Cortana, but then Search on your own HDD (or SSD) no longer works.

You can disable Cloud Search, voice response and other aspects of Cortana, either through the [Registry key](https://www.howtogeek.com/265027/how-to-disable-cortana-in-windows-10/) `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Search`, or using a third-party tool such as [O&O ShutUp10](https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10), shown below.

[image: O&O ShutUp10 Cortana settings]

Comment: Be very careful with ShupUp10 though. It can irreversibly break (some) Windows functionality.