# How to disable internet search results in start menu post Creators Update?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1703, cortana, windows-10-v1803

It [used to be possible](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-bing-search-windows-10-start-menu) to disable internet search results in start menu searches before the Windows 10 Creators Update, but I've just clean installed a new Windows 10 Pro image and that setting is gone. Is there some way to disable it through editing the registry/etc?

Answer (score 241, accepted):

The article
[The Windows 10 spring update no longer lets you disable web search in Start - workaround](https://www.neowin.net/news/the-windows-10-spring-update-no-longer-lets-you-disable-web-search-in-start) reports that the following registry update
is required in Windows 10 version 1803 :

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search]
"BingSearchEnabled"=dword:00000000
"AllowSearchToUseLocation"=dword:00000000
"CortanaConsent"=dword:00000000
```

It remarks :

> those entries are completely missing from the "Search" registry key, so you can safely delete them should you want to revert.

I would still recommend to at least create a system restore point before doing
any registry modifications.

A reboot might be required.

User @mtd has contributed below these commands for applying the updates to
the registry:

```
reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search /f /v BingSearchEnabled /t REG_DWORD /d 0
reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search /f /v AllowSearchToUseLocation /t REG_DWORD /d 0
reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search /f /v CortanaConsent /t REG_DWORD /d 0
```

---

EDIT1 : There are reports that Windows 10 version 2004 has broken the above fix.

The article
[Disable Web Search in Taskbar in Windows 10 Version 2004](https://winaero.com/blog/disable-web-search-in-taskbar-in-windows-10-version-2004/)
has a summary of the current state of the problem.

The current solution seems to be to download and run this
[PowerShell script](https://winaero.com/request.php?2378)
as Administrator:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process
.\disable-web-search.ps1
```

As only a workaround, this PowerShell script blocks the online search using
Windows Firewall rules, so forcing the search to operate in offline mode.

---

EDIT2: Reports now say that these registry modification are working for
Windows versions 2004 and 20H2 without reboot.

---

EDIT3: Windows 11 21H2 - it has been reported that it is
also required to create in the registry key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer`,
a DWORD32 value named `DisableSearchBoxSuggestions`
and set its value to `1`.

More information in the article
[How to Disable Web Search Results in Start Menu on Windows 11](https://allthings.how/how-to-disable-web-search-results-in-start-menu-on-windows-11/).

Comment: Confirmed that these registry edits successfully disable the web search. The start menu wasn't turning up many search results on my local disk when I initially made those registry changes (even after restarting explorer.exe), but after a few minutes that problem resolved itself.

Comment: You can just kill `SearchUI.exe` to have this kick in. When you then open the search panel -- `Win+S` -- it should say "apps, files and settings". If it still states "web results", make sure you added **all** keys. In my case, `CortanaConsent` was missing.

Comment: I went through every step in https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-windows-10-start-menu-search/ and was still left without working search. Disabling internet results fixed it instantly. Thanks!

Comment: Note, the reg file in the link contains weird quotes. I copied the code block from this answer and it works fine.

Comment: For some reason I couldn't see `BingSearchEnabled` or `AllowSearchToUseLocation` in the register editor GUI but I was able to disable web searches by running this in cmd `reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search /f /v BingSearchEnabled /t REG_DWORD /d 0`

Comment: @CharlesClayton Thanks for that.  All three commands together are:
`reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search /f /v BingSearchEnabled /t REG_DWORD /d 0`
`reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search /f /v AllowSearchToUseLocation /t REG_DWORD /d 0`
`reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search /f /v CortanaConsent /t REG_DWORD /d 0`

Comment: Confirmed working on Windows 10 Enterprise 1709 .

Comment: works on 1903 ✔

Comment: I just tested, and reboot isn't required.

Comment: This appears to have broken search altogether. No results appear anymore.

Comment: Not my comment but "The search from start menu might be broken after this; to fix just restart SearchUI.exe".

Comment: For me Search still works, but is restricted to local content.. Finally my start menu is showing me the installed applications (and not links to their manufacturer's web site) +1.

Comment: Maybe this is obvious, but just in case it isn't: open `regedit` as user (not admin) to make these changes!

Comment: Works on 1909 ✔, no reboot required

Comment: I didn't need to reboot, but I did need to manually kill `explorer.exe` from the Task Manager to get this working

Comment: CortanaConsent=0 essentially blocks all future updates to start menu search index; no amount of index rebuild or reset fixes it until cortanaconsent is restored

Comment: This no longer works on update 2004. BingSearchEnabled and AllowSearchToUseLocation are no longer there.

Comment: @JSLavertu: Thanks for the information. See my addition to the answer for a possible solution. Please report if it worked for you.

Comment: @harrymc I followed similar steps from another guide. It doesn't disable web search, but it does prevent it from working, so that's a start. Thanks!

Comment: Can you [try](https://www.howtogeek.com/224159/how-to-disable-bing-in-the-windows-10-start-menu/) `reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer /f /v DisableSearchBoxSuggestions /t REG_DWORD /d 1`?

Comment: Is it someone's job at Microsoft to purposely annoy people?

Comment: It worked for me on update 2004 using the `reg add` commands, withouth rebooting

Comment: Same for version 20H2 without rebooting

Comment: Works on 21H1 ✔, no reboot required

Comment: Since this post is highly rated on Google: For Windows 11 21H2, the above didn't work but this article pointed me in the right direction: https://allthings.how/how-to-disable-web-search-results-in-start-menu-on-windows-11/ It's a case of using regedit to add the key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer and set DWORD value DisableSearchBoxSuggestions to 1. (I also disabled via local group policy and the above registry keys, but neither had any effect.) Restarting Explorer only was fine rather than rebooting.

Comment: @ElZorko: Thanks, I have added the information to the answer.

Answer (score 103):

This has been required since Windows 10 Version 1607.  Configuring the group policies below will only work if you are running Windows 10 Version 1607, Windows 10 Version 1703, or Windows 10 Version 1709.  You must be running **Windows 10 Professional or any applicable version of Windows 10** for these group policy changes to take effect.

> 1. Start the *Local Group Policy Editor*
> 2. The policy you’re looking for is located at
>
> > Computer Configuration → Administrative Templates → Windows
> > Components → Search
>
> 3. Set *Allow Cortana* to **Disable**
> 4. Set *Do not allow web search* to **Enabled**
> 5. Set *Don't search the web or display web results in Search* to **Enabled**
> 6. Restart

[image]

Image Source:

- [How to Disable Cortana in Windows 10’s Anniversary Update](https://www.howtogeek.com/265027/how-to-disable-cortana-in-windows-10/)

Additional Sources:

- [Disable & Turn Off Cortana in Windows 10](https://techjourney.net/disable-turn-off-cortana-in-windows-10/)
- [Don't search the web or display web results in Search](https://superuser.com/questions/947156/how-do-i-disable-cortana-in-windows-10-or-at-least-disable-web-search-results-fr)
- [How To Remove/Disable Web Search From Windows 10](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/remove-disable-web-search-from-windows-10/).
- [Search/DoNotUseWebResults](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/policy-csp-search#search-donotusewebresults)
- [What's new in Windows 10, version 1803](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/new-in-windows-mdm-enrollment-management#a-href-idwhatsnew1803awhats-new-in-windows-10-version-1803)

Answer (score 9):

While @Ramhound [solution](https://superuser.com/a/1196624/900431) and @harrymc [solution](https://superuser.com/a/1325836/900431) are certainly the most direct, there is also a useful free third part program, that can edit many of these hidden settings, including the turning off of Internet Search in Cortana.

> **O&O ShutUp10** means you have full control over which comfort functions
>   under Windows 10 you wish to use, and you decide when the passing on
>   of your data goes too far. Using a very simple interface, you decide
>   how Windows 10 should respect your privacy by deciding which unwanted
>   functions should be deactivated.
>
> O&O ShutUp10 is entirely free and does not have to be installed – it
>   can be simply run directly and immediately on your PC. And it will not
>   install or download retrospectively unwanted or unnecessary software,
>   like so many other programs do these days!
>
> ( [Website](https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10) and [Direct Download](https://dl5.oo-software.com/files/ooshutup10/OOSU10.exe) )

*Example of cortana settings in the program:*

[image: Cortana Settings]

Comment: oo-software.com is reliable? How to confirm that there are no trojan?

Comment: @PeterKrauss You will have to read up on them your self. They have been around for a long term, a german company, and are certified microsoft partner; see there history here https://www.oo-software.com/en/company

Comment: @PeterKrauss basically they have been around for a long time, and there products can be found across the internet. [cnet page](https://download.cnet.com/developer/o-o-software/i-6267447) , [mwc](https://www.mwcbarcelona.com/exhibitor/oo-software-gmbh/) , [amazon](https://www.amazon.com/stores/OOSoftwareGmbH/node/8172048011) , [shop](https://www.dobreprogramy.pl/OO-Software-GmbH,Producent,747.html) , [shop2](https://www.newegg.com/o-o-software-diskimage-15-pro-download/p/N82E16832475009?Description=O%20%26%20O&cm_re=O_%26_O-_-32-475-009-_-Product).

Comment: Ok ok, it is like any other black-box: non-reliable. Only auditable (simple and non-chaotic) **open source is reliable**. But, no other options for ugly-Windows, ok: german company and long term sorftware (confirmed), and your approval, it is a good credential. ...I used and was good (!), more one up vote!

Comment: Every other solution on this page did not work except this one

Answer (score -3):

And for these who is looking for disabling web search via registry:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Search`

create new 32-bit DWORD value **ConnectedSearchUseWeb** and set it to **0**

Reboot.

[Reference](https://www.top-password.com/blog/disable-cortana-web-search-in-windows-10/)

Comment: This doesn't work on Windows 10 home

Comment: @NatanYellin what if you add **DisableWebSearch** DWORD and set it to **1**
Maybe reboot is required after all?

Comment: Nope, that doesn't fix it either. The entire key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Search" didn't exist originally. I created it, added both DWORDs you mentioned, rebooted... And websearch is still enabled.