# Windows 10 search results empty unless filter applied

Tags: windows, windows-10, start-menu, windows-search

When I search any term in the Start Menu, I never get local results:
[image]

That is, until I manually apply a filter to the search:
[image]

Then for some reason, it works properly. Does anyone have a fix? Haven't found one in any similar Super User question/online forum.

Comment: Have you disabled indexing?

Comment: [Disable](https://superuser.com/questions/1196618/how-to-disable-internet-search-results-in-start-menu-post-creators-update/1196624#1196624) internet searches and see if you have better results.

Comment: @RadialApps all the files are properly indexed (as shown in results when a filter is applied)

Comment: @Ramhound I've searched and installed `gpedit.msc` (I have Windows 10 Home), but the "Search" folder is missing in the editor

Comment: @pqn That means you will have to apply the changes to the appropriate keys yourself

Answer (score 0):

Turn UAC back on.
To verify if this is your problem, check the following logs in event viewer.
Application

And

Applications and Services logs - Microsoft- Windows - Apps

If you see anything regarding Cortana or SearchUI that says "This application cannot be activated by the built-in Administrator" - It's because you've disabled either UAC or the Windows Firewall Service.

This will deny required permissions to Cortana - which happens to be a key component of Windows Search.