# How to disable web results from Windows Search (Windows 10 Home)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-search, gpedit, windows-10-v1903

Whenever I search anything in Windows 10 (<kbd>⊞</kbd> > Start Typing), Windows shows web results (from Bing) on the top, even if I have a file with the exact name as the search term, or the search term matches some text in a file. This is very annoying as I have to press <kbd>▽</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter ←<sup>l</sup></kbd> every time I need to open something quickly. It does not even search the files and folders properly and shows some really useless web results.

I searched the web for instructions on disabling web results from Windows search, but they were either "*patched* " by Microsoft, or required **Local Group Policy Editor** (GPEdit.msc), which Windows 10 Home doesn't have. I tried to download it, but Microsoft's website has [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=21895), which is for Windows XP/Windows Server 2003.

Can web results from Windows 10 search be disabled in **Windows 10 Home** without GPEdit?
If not, how can I get GPEdit in **Windows 10 Home**?

---

Version: `1903` 
Build: `18362.145`

---

**Edit: The 1903 update did make search better, but when I search for something when the HDD is being used, it can't search fast enough and shows web results till the time it finishes the search.**

Comment: While there are registry keys, it’s far easier, just to add the group policy editor to home [instructions](https://superuser.com/questions/1018145/windows-starter-edition-home-and-home-premium-do-not-include-gpedit-how-do-i-i/1018146#1018146).

Comment: Working solution that is applicable to 1803+ and thus a duplicate candidate https://superuser.com/questions/1196618/how-to-disable-internet-search-results-in-start-menu-post-creators-update/1196624#1196624 the group policies don’t even work on 1903 (although the editor is still helpful to have)