# Block Bing Search on Windows 10 build 1903

Tags: windows-10, cortana, bing

I found answers about modifying the registry with "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search" for 1803, **but in 1903 the registry keys dont seem to exist, or have been moved.**

How to disable Bing from the search and ideally turn off Cortana altogether.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable internet search results in start menu post Creators Update?](https://superuser.com/questions/1196618/how-to-disable-internet-search-results-in-start-menu-post-creators-update)

Comment: Not a duplicate, as my post says the registry keys are no longer there

Comment: You indicated the linked answer is indeed correct thus this is a duplicate of the existing question.

Answer (score -1):

The linked answer is in fact correct, but it states it is a registry edit, whereas in fact in 1903 you must ADD the registry keys, except for CortanaConsent which already existed on my system.

Comment: The linked answer already indicates you must also add the registry keys.