# How do I turn off Windows 10 searching the store when I press start and type?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1903, windows-10-pro

I just upgraded to Windows 10 1903 and now when I press Start and type Windows is showing store results

[image]

How do I turn that feature off? I don't want windows searching the store when I press the start key and type

Note: I tried the solutions listed [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_cortana/disable-store-and-web-search-in-start-menu/106f43ca-1d17-4cd6-a17f-88bd1eeb7121). The Group Policies didn't make any noticeable changes (yes, I rebooted after enabling them). The notebook reference seems to be non-Pro as no such options show up.

Comment: This [method](https://superuser.com/a/1325836/8672) might help.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - Reverting to a previous feature update really isn't a helpful suggestion considering that eventually the author will be forced to use Windows 10 version 1903 within the next 8 months.

Comment: Actually, the comment was a bit sarcastic... when an update removes a vital setting, it's not much progress.