# Disable Bing Search on Windows Start Menu for Standard Users

Tags: windows-registry, privacy, windows-search, regedit, standard-user

I found that the [How-to-Geek Guide - How to Disable Bing in the Windows 10 Start Menu](https://www.howtogeek.com/224159/how-to-disable-bing-in-the-windows-10-start-menu/) works also for Windows 11 (or at least for versions prior to 22h2).

I have more than one account on my machine, only one as Administrator, the others are Standard Users.
The guide works for the Administrator, but the  added register key is not applied to the other Standard Users registers. I can verify this because the Bing search is still active and their register remains unaffected. Obviously it is not possible to modify register keys from a Standard User.

So the question is, how can i add a such register key on a Standard User account (using the Home version of Windows)?

Comment: The key there is `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer` - have you tried applying it in `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer`? If you do, please remember to backup the key first in case something goes wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 disable internet in search](https://superuser.com/questions/1557948/windows-10-disable-internet-in-search).  You can use your Administrator account to apply it to the HKEY_CURRENT_USER for the unprivilaged account.

Comment: I tried it and it worked! thank you!