# How to disable web search in search icon windows 10

Tags: windows-10, search, start-menu, web, bing

Go to Windows Defender Firewall settings > Advanced setting > Outbound rules> Windows Search > properties > block the connection > apply > ok.
This is working for me. 100%.
Any other methods I can try ?.

Comment: This can only be done in the firewall, you have found the solution.

Comment: You might also want to block Cortana connections, https://www.ghacks.net/2016/02/29/cortana-block-outbound-network-connections-completely/

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1196618/how-to-disable-internet-search-results-in-start-menu-post-creators-update/1196624#1196624) has a working answer for all supported versions of Windows 10