# How to keep local searches local on Win11?

Tags: windows-11, privacy, privacy-protection

To launch a program on Windows 11 I press the win-key and type the name of the software.
But there is a huge privacy issue with the latest version of Windows:

- The system sends everything the user types to the Internet, as the web suggestions that appear in the start menu confirm.
- In the case there is no local result and I type enter, Windows opens Bing on Edge browser and looks for my local search.

I do not see how sending local searches from my computer to the Internet without my approval is in any way acceptable and worst I do not find any way to counter this breach of privacy.

How to keep local searches totally local on Windows 11?

Comment: See if [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1196618/how-to-disable-internet-search-results-in-start-menu-post-creators-update/1325836#1325836) of mine is still relevant in Windows 11. Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Search and then constraint to Documents. Are you sure the request goes out to the Internet?   I do not think so.

Comment: According to [this](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/enable-or-disable-search-the-web-with-bing-in-windows-search-in-windows-11.5309/) the existing answer appear to be applicable to Windows 11